# Accessing single scene image file in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am reading the example in Google Earth Engine was many using the Image Collection but I can't find a single scene reading the image so I am trying to calculate for single scene using Landsat 8 OLI for 09 January 2019 but have a problem reading the scene then calculate NDVI from single scene, this is the script :

```
var tuban = ee.FeatureCollection("users/iqbal/Tuban");

var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_L1TP_119065_20190109_20190130_01_T1')
// Get information about the bands as a list.
var bandNames = image.bandNames();
print('Band names: ', bandNames); // ee.List of band names

// Get projection information from band 1.
var b1proj = image.select('B1').projection();
print('Band 1 projection: ', b1proj); // ee.Projection object

// Get scale (in meters) information from band 1.
//var b1scale = image.select('B1').projection().nominalScale();
//print('Band 1 scale: ', b1scale); // ee.Number

// create function to add NDVI using NIR (B5) and the red band (B4)
var getNDVI = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// map over image collection
var l8ndvi = image.map(getNDVI);

var composite = l8ndvi.qualityMosaic('NDVI').clip(tuban);
print(composite);

// Visualize NDVI
var ndviPalette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
Map.addLayer(composite.select('NDVI'),
            {min:0, max: 1, palette: ndviPalette}, 'ndvi');
```

There is some error for accessing the single scene like this:

```
Band names: 
List (Error)
Image.load: Image asset 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_L1TP_119065_20190109_20190130_01_T1' not found.
Band 1 projection: 
Projection (Error)
Image.load: Image asset 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_L1TP_119065_20190109_20190130_01_T1' not found.
image.map is not a function
``
Any suggestions as a solution for this?
```

Answer (score 1):

The naming convention you've used is mixture of google earth engine and Landsat documentation.

Landsat uses the following naming convention

```
LXSS_LLLL_PPPRRR_YYYYMMDD_yyyymmdd_CC_TX
```

read about it [here](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-naming-convention-landsat-collections-level-1-scenes?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products)

while in google earth engine you do not specify the Processing year, month, day or collection number.
The convention in GEE is

```
LANDSAT/LXSS/C01/TX/LXSS_PPPRRR_YYYYMMDD
```

another error: `image.map is not a function` is because mapping is done over image collection not a single image